# vimeo background video is not playing in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have added vimeo video as background.
This video playing automatically in **firefox** and **IE** but not **chrome** and **safari**.

This is my HTML

```
<section id="intro">
</section>
```

This is my CSS

```
#intro {
width: 100%;
height: 700px;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 150, 200, 1), rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.4)), url(https://player.vimeo.com/video/188755936) center top no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
```

Here is my domain. https://www.appail.com/

and here is attached screenshot to check my css.

[image]

Comment: How is this a `css` problem ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT ACCEPTABLE.

Comment: That i don't know. that is what i posted my issue here..

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, The vimeo video calling from css.

Comment: Don't use a iframe for this. Use [video tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: I'm calling video through css. And vimeo videos will come along with iframe na! I have added my code here. Check once my question na...

Comment: Vimeo seems to not allow people to embed their videos directly, therefor the video won't play in iframe. take a look at this https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mute the video? As you can read in [this](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos) article it should be works. Just add ?muted=1 to the end of the player URL in your embed code.

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos

Comment: This link is working for me,  try to copy and paste it in to the address bar

Comment: Thanks, For your information, this is not iframe. I have <section class="intro"> tag and calling css with class name. Can you see my question again plz..

Comment: Yes of course, I see your question again but if you use the Chrome Developer Tools in the link that you have provided you will see the IFRAME inside ".video-foreground", inside ".video-background", inside the section with the id="intro". So this is an iframe